# Draggable disabled after opening a MUI modal, tooltip and popover

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, drag-and-drop

I use React MUI and some components disable my draggables.

I have put draggables on my page, that works perfectly.
When my draggable is dragged, I change some nodes in the page.

I'm on React MUI and I use tooltips, modals and menus on that page. After opening one of them and close it, no draggables can be dragged anymore. I mean that changing some nodes in the page makes that the drag ends directly.

Is there an event inserted or something like that that ends the drag action if an element is changing in the page ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.
Actually this happens on Chrome and Safari only. Adding a `setTimeout` of 10ms before changing the DOM makes the job.